# Add a field to select the associated product to a opportunity in Sugarcrm Ce / Suitecrm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want to add a custom field in the Opportunity creation that points to the associated product. I don't know if is possible using the studio, i tried and doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own answer: using a Relate field in the Studio.